# When does the Roll Up fields are calculated?

Tags: trigger, roll-up-summary

Well while doing some research found that **Rollup** fields are not updated in **after trigger**(am querying the field again using an SOQL from the trigger). This seems to be unexpected as per my knowledge they should be updated in **after trigger**.

Is it something expected or am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm):

> Calculating roll-up summary field values may take up to 30 minutes,
>   depending on the number of records affected and other factors.

Since they are updated asynchronously it would make sense you might not see the new value in your trigger. Indeed, the documentation mentions that they can trigger workflow rules and field validations but makes no mention of how they interact with a `trigger`.

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but in looking at the current documentation I think that 30 minutes is referring to the time if you make a change to the field. This is because the documentation also states "Salesforce prevents users from saving a record if it invalidates a related record. For example, a master record has a validation rule that requires the roll-up summary field value to be greater than 100. If the user’s change to a related child record would put the value over 100, the user can’t save the record." In order to perform validation checks the calculation needs to be immediate.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the order salesforce logic is applied to a record:
1.    Old record loaded from database (or initialized for new inserts)

1. New record values overwrite old values
2. System Validation Rules
3. All Apex “before” triggers (EE / UE only)
4. Custom Validation Rules
5. Record saved to database (but not committed)
6. Record reloaded from database
7. All Apex “after” triggers (EE / UE only)
8. Assignment rules
9. Auto-response rules
10. Workflow rules
11. Escalation rules
12. Parent Rollup Summary Formula value updated (if present)
13. Database commit
14. Post-commit logic (sending email)

Additional notes: There is no way to control the order of execution within each group above

In other words, SF will get to it when they get to it. If you want it "NOW", you need to add the feature to your trigger as an aggregate function.